# Flow is not triggered under certain condition, but it should be

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, process-automation

I have an object called Lever__c which is a child of Opportunity.

We'll consider here the following fields :

- Opportunity.CloseDate
- Lever__c.CloseDate__c //copies from opp.
- Lever__c.ApplicationDay__c //diff in days between CloseDate and ApplicationDate
- Lever__c.ApplicationDate__c //CloseDate__c + ApplicationDay__c
- Lever__c.Status__c //picklist

When `Opportunity.CloseDate`is modified, a Process Builder is triggered, with 2 actions :

1. If Lever.Status not in ('Draft', 'Cancelled', null) then `Lever.Status = 'To revalidate'`
2. No criteria, `Lever__c.CloseDate__c = Opportunity.CloseDate`

So far so good, it works perfectly.

Then there is a flow triggered **before insert/update** on object Lever__c, no condition.
This flow has a decision who returns YES if any criteria is met (only OR, no AND). There are several conditions including `Record__prior.CloseDate__c != Record.CloseDate__c`. No condition is about status.
It recalculates the ApplicationDate__c  field by adding ApplicationDay__c to Opportunity__r.CloseDate.

So when the process builder is run, the CloseDate__c is updated, the flow is then triggered and the ApplicationDate__c filed is updated.

**Except** that it works *unless* the Lever__c.Status is `To revalidate`.

It's like the flow is triggered unless all the actions defined in the process builder are  executed. There is a STOP after the actions, maybe that's it, I'm going to try to remove it, but for me the STOP depends on the initial condition (left column in Process Builder) not on the actions actual executions. And for me it prevents the Process Builder to evaluate next lines, not flows or apex triggers to be triggered...

[EDIT] I tried to remove STOP and replace with Evaluate next criteria but it changed nothing...

Comment: I solved the problem by moving the 2nd action : update CloseDate__c to a 2nd process builder. It makes no sense to me...

Comment: I got slightly confused at the end, please clarify: 1] Your Flow is NOT changing things when `Lever__c.Status__c` is set to `To revalidate` when you DO want it to change?  Or 2] it IS changing things when you do NOT want it to?

Comment: It should and it does not. It's like the filter on Oppportunity.Lever__r from the first PB action does not apply for the second PB action (which is normal) but does apply in the flow triggered by this second action.  Yeah well it is confusing, and it makes no sense...

Comment: I think I might have an idea of your original issue, so tried to recreate your Process Builder process in a sandbox. But I got confused trying to follow how you described it.  Can you edit your question and add a screenshot of your original Process Builder process? I don't think I need to see the details of each criterion or action right now (unless you just really want to include them) - just an overview of the process.